# Create a user in Active Directory from an Infopath form

Tags: vb6, vbscript, active-directory, infopath

I've been searching the web for a while now and still can't seem to find anything useful on this topic.

What I am trying to create is a button in my Infopath form that will create a user account in Active Directory.  The code will need to pull through information stored in the fields of the Infopath form.

I have chosen to use Visual Basic, as I believe that is a good language scripting with AD.

I have successfully run this code:

```
Sub CTRL1_12_OnClick(eventObj)
 MsgBox "Output: "
End Sub
```

which returns:  **'Output: '** in a VB dialogue box when I click on my infopath button.  However, when I try:

```
Set objOU=GetObject("LDAP://OU=People,OU=contoso,DC=contoso,DC=com")
Set objUser=objOU.Create("user","CN=Linda Mitchell")
objUser.Put "sAMAccountName","linda.mitchell"
objUser.SetInfo()
```

All I get is an error message in Infopath:

> The following error occurred:
>
> ActiveX component can't create object:
>   'GetObject' File:script.vbs Line:14

When I put the same code in to notepad, save as a vbs file and then execute is runs fine and create a user in active directory, what I don't understand is why when I run the same code it doesn't work.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Will do, didn't see that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found out what the problem was.  I needed to set the form to 'full trust' Tools>form options> Security and Trust.  I also had to sign the form with my certificate.

Now I am able to run the code from that button.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check out Richard Mueller's web site - he has tons of VBScript code to do all sorts of AD stuff.

Here's a [link to a page](http://www.rlmueller.net/CreateUsers.htm) showing how to create users - is that of help?? I'm not much of a VBScript programmer, but I know Richard's stuff is usually very good and useful.

Here's his entire [list of free VBScript code](http://www.rlmueller.net/products.htm) for you to go rummage about!

Comment: Thanks for that, his website looks pretty good and I may be able to use his code once I find out why this code doesn't work in Infopath but runs fine in a standalone vbs script on my desktop.

Peter